# How to show a quasi-order ~ on a set S with relation // induces a partially ordered relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Let ~ be the quasi-order relation. and let // be defined as the relation s~t and t~s(s,t elements of S).
Show that ~ induces a partially ordered relation on the set of equivalence classes relation //, denoted S/(//) "quotient set"

I haven't had much experience with set theory and need help with what I need to actually show here.

Comment: It's a good idea to start with the definitions, as these exercises are almost surely intended to reinforce familiarity with them.  What does it mean that ~ is a *quasi-order* relation, or that // (which is determined by ~) is an *equivalence* relation (it is)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sim$ is a preorder or quasiorder, so we know that it's reflexive and transitive.

$$x \sim x$$
$$x \sim y ∧ y \sim z → x \sim z$$

To show that $\sim$ is a partial order on $//$ we need the facts above and we need to prove that it's antisymmetric (on $//$).

$$x \sim y ∧ y \sim x → x \: // \: y$$

But this is a trivial consequence of the definition $x \: // \: y ↔ x \sim y ∧ y \sim x$.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I am confused about why we need to prove the mapping(or is it an implication symbol?)

Comment: I've edited the answer. It is the implication symbol, but the distinction between implication and mapping is probably [smaller than you might think](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence).

Comment: Great. I think I understand. except when they call it a quotient set what does that mean? Does that mean the set with such relation?